# replace spaces with _ in php

Tags: php, spaces

i am trying to replace spaces with underscore '_' in the following variable

```
 $e_type = 'Hello World TEST';
```

can anyone help me please

Comment: Downvote because its such a "lazy" question to post or leave it alone because it is still a valid question? Tough

Comment: You would have much less work todo if you used google. ;-) http://www.google.ch/search?q=php%20string%20replace%20spaces%20with%20underscore

Comment: @sandro but we try to get rid of google, stackoverflow is so much better :-)

Answer (score 51, accepted):

You want [`str_replace`](http://www.php.net/str_replace):

```
$e_type = str_replace(' ', '_', $e_type);
```

Answer (score 8):

[str_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php)

Answer (score 4):

[Check this](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php). You have some nice examples there...